# Browserify: Uncaught error when requiring js file by path created from string concatenation

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am using browesify for client side app. I have files `maps.js` and `directions.js` sitting besides my `index.js` file, and inside my `index.js`, I have a function `getPageName()` which returns the name of the file that I should "require". When I try to do

```
var pageName = getPageName();
var page;
if (pageName === 'maps') {
    page = require('./maps');
} else if (pageName === 'directions') {
    page = require('./directions');
}
```

it works fine. But when I instead try to use following trick to minimize my code,

```
var pageName = getPageName();
var page = require('./' + pageName);
```

I get error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './maps'` in console log in Chrome. Why does it not work when I use string concatenation but works when I use pass the path explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a limitation of Browserify and similar type libraries. In order to do the `require()` the library has to examine the js code as a string, and determine file paths before the code is run. This means file paths have to be static in order for it to be picked up.

> https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/377
>
> Browserify can only analyze static requires. It is not in the scope of
>   browserify to handle dynamic requires